# How is $\Bbb K$ well defined, operator algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

The letter $\Bbb K$ in [Bruce Blackadar, on operator algebra](https://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/bruceb/Cycr.pdf) denotes the algebra of compact operators on a separable infinite dimensional hilbert space, $H$.

---

In my other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135984/c-algebra-of-compact-operators-as-a-direct-limit-of-matrix-algebras), it is shown that  $M_\infty(\Bbb C)$ is isomoprhic to $\Bbb K$ set-wise.

My questions are as follows:

(i) We can give $M_\infty(\Bbb C)$ a $*$-algebra structure. If each embedding is an isometric isomorphism, in the colimit diagram, we can also give it the norm. Does this also make $M_\infty(\Bbb C)$ a $C^*$ algebra?

(ii) How is $\Bbb K$ independent of choice of $H$? Where is separablility used?

---

Partial replies or references are appreciated.

Comment: I found the answer on page 53 just by using the symbol index in the book.

Comment: E.g., "We  denote by $\mathbb{K}$ the C*-algebra of compact operators on a separable, infinite-dimensionalHilbert space.  "

Comment: Ok, thanks  a lot, now I reformulated my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i)  It does make $M_\infty(\mathbb{C})$ a C$^*$-algebra, but it might be worth mentioning that $M_\infty(\mathbb{C})$ is to be interpreted as the direct limit described in that post and not as the collection of all infinite matrices $\{(a_{ij})_{i, j \in \mathbb{N}}: a_{ij} \in \mathbb{C}\}$.  The latter has pathological unbounded examples like $a_{ij} = \delta_{ij}j$.  Also, the isomorphism described in your post is an isomorphism of C$^*$-algebras (not just sets).

(ii) We're using the separability assumption because there's only one separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space up to unitary equivalence, and any unitary $U: H \rightarrow H'$ induces a $*$-isomoprhism (Ad $U$) between $K(H)$ and $K(H')$.  So $K$ is independent of $H$ up to isomorphism.

In general, there's one Hilbert space for each cardinal (representing the cardinality of a basis for $H$).  The separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is the one with a countably infinite basis, so as long as we restrict to the separable case, $K$ is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks  a lot Josh. I hope you can comment on my newest post. It is quite related to this problem.